# how to filter data from parant model based on if there relationship with child model

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have these models

```
class Tree(models.Model):
    field = models.TextField()

class TaskProgress(models.Model):
    base_task = models.ForeignKey(BaseTask, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tree = models.ForeignKey(Tree, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class BaseTask(models.Model):
   trees=models.ManyToManyField(Tree, through='TaskProgress')


class TaskType1(BaseTask):
   child1_field = models.TextField()

class TaskType2(BaseTask):
   child2_field = models.TextField()
```

how to get all taskprogress when related to TaskType2 ,

```
TaskProgress.objects.filter(???)
```

Comment: can you give scenario how these  models can be filtered? any example? as it is really tough to get when models are not related to each other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added extra field on BaseTask class

```
TASK_TYPE =[('I','Irrigation'),('C','Care'),('A','Assessment'),('O','Other')]

class BaseTask(models.Model):
    trees=models.ManyToManyField(Tree, through='TaskProgress')
    worker = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    task_type = models.CharField(max_length=1,choices=TASK_TYPE,null=True)
```

And the filter will be like this

```
TaskProgress.objects.filter(base_task__task = "I")
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not think what you are asking is possible, if the models are designed like described. The base_task ForeignKey is specifically pointing at a BaseTask. Even though TaskType1 and TaskType2 inherit from BaseTask, they have no relation in the database. They only look similar.

Option 1: Look into [Generic Relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations) in Django. Basically it allows you to have a ForeignKey relation with more than one type of model. I would not recommend it though. Generic relations are a mess if you don't know want you are doing.

Option 2: Rethink your layout. Maybe you can move the relation to the two TaskTypes instead and adress them via related_name.

```
class TaskProgress(models.Model):
    # base_task = models.ForeignKey(BaseTask, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tree = models.ForeignKey(Tree, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class TaskType1(BaseTask):
   task_progress = models.OneToOneField(TaskProgress, related_name='task_type_1'
   child1_field = models.TextField()

class TaskType2(BaseTask):
   task_progress = models.OneToOneField(TaskProgress, related_name='task_type_2'
   child2_field = models.TextField()
```

This way you create a one-to-one-relation between the TaskProgress and the TaskType. You should be able to query one or the other by checking whether a relation exists, e.g. all TaskProgress instances with a relation to a TaskType1 instance.

```
# Query all TaskProgress instances, that have a TaskType1
TaskProgress.objects.filter(task_type_1__isnull=False)
```

Comment: tahnk you for this useful answer , 
this is the first time i know about  Generic Relations this may help me later  

about your answer , the relation ship between basetask and taskprogress is many-to-many not one-to-many , and this will make extra tables on data base and this is no good for performance

Comment: Well, in that case simply replace models.OneToOneField with models.ManyToManyField. Using related names is still works. 
Why would you you use ForeignKey for a many to many relationship in you example? ForeignKey is meant for one-to-many relationships.